# How to integrate Crashlytics with Github?

Tags: crashlytics

Did anyone have any success integrating crashlytics with github, I'm not really sure how relevant this question would be here?

I have android app already on github, and I have crashltyics correctly integrated in the app, but I tried to link it to the github repository and I'm always gettings, couldn't access repository (I contacted them so many time but they never replied) I'm 100% sure I generated the token as described (as I already did this for other apps) but Crashlytics is always rejecting this github token.

did anyone have success integrating it?

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
Could not access repository for https://github.com/User/Repository
```

I followed the steps as per this link:

https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

I also tried to do this with one of my open-source libs

https://github.com/shehabic/closeby

but it didn't work either, I'm not sure if it's me or crashlytics Github integration is not working

Comment: Your Your GitHub repository is wrong. just add  "shehabic/closeby" and your token

Comment: I already answered this question below (2 years ago)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I finally got a reply from them and found out how to do it:

Simply when entering the repository in the corresponding field enter is as follows:

```
user/repo
```

instead of

```
http://github.com/user/repo
```

the integration is not really that powerful, it just creates an issue with just 1 line, without any referral to the code repo in github

Comment: Thanks exactly same problem

Comment: Super annoying that fabric doesn't just specify this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same problem but i fixed it as follows,

Step1 : Your GitHub repository: Company Name>/Repository Name
    e.g `cmpanyXYZ/abcd`
(Note : 1. do not use .git at end of repository name. 2. You can find this details in repository clone url)

Step 2 : Generate access token from [here](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/)
        Copy generated token in step2 box from image.

Now Click on Verify button

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Firebase -> Crashlytics.
Follow the documentation step by step.
There is also a script demonstrating how to force crash and test the app.
Make sure you give the correct path of Google Info pList file in
the AppDelegate.